# Adding gridlines to Wt WTable Widget

Tags: c++, wt

I am attempting to using the Wt web framework to create a HTML table object.  I cannot see a way of adding the table gridlines (a la border="1" in an HTML table) to the table.  I can encapsulate the entire table widget with a border using

```
partTable->decorationStyle().setBorder(border);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style your table using CSS.

Create a stylesheet:

```
.my-table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Add it to your application:

```
wApp->useStyleSheet("my_stylesheet.css");
```

Then set the `my-table` css class to your table:

```
table->addStyleClass("my-table");
```

Or you can set `WCssDecorationStyle` to every table cell:

```
const Wt::WBorder border(Wt::WBorder::Solid, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < table->rowCount(); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < table->columnCount(); ++j)
    {
        table->elementAt(i, j)->decorationStyle().setBorder(border);
    }
}
```